# Android layout: How would you try to achieve this?

Tags: android, layout

The following layout should be achieved and displayed consistently on all screens (phone, tablet, phablet)

1. Landscape only
2. Top/left an imageview, always 16:9, probably covering
   2/3rd of the width
3. Right of this a textview, 1/3rd width, full height
   (well, maybe a little marigin at to bottom and top aligned with the
   image view)
4. Two buttons on the bottom, left and right aligned
   with the imageview.

Any pointer, how that could be achieved? I tried with sw320, sw480 and sw600 layouts, but there is always that one special device, on which the buttons overlap the image....

[image]

Comment: constraint layout is will be helpful.

Comment: ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. The problem is, that I cannot figure out, how to make the image view always as big as possible while keeping the aspect ratio. I really have a heavily constrained layout (BTW I found the layout editor ways better than the XCode stuff), but the results are not that good. I think there is a "keep aspect ratio" constraints, but my biggest problem is to find _the_setup, which makes my imageview always using 2/3rd and leaving 1/3rd at the right while keeping the aspect ratio of 16:9. Haven't found anything which works under all circumstances

Comment: Oh wait, app:layout_constraintWidth_percent seems to be a good friend...

Comment: Yes, solution was the app:layout_constraintWidth_percent

Answer (score 0):

You can use constraint layout in this case. Constraint edges of all object with each other and edges of the object which is near to the edge, constraint it with layout edge. You can also find more information about this on android developer website or YouTube.